# How to save nested route records in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello beautiful community. I am a newbie in Rails and I have a project where I have to register patients and each patient has evolutions. I have been able to register and save the patients in the database, but I cannot save the records of the evolution of these patients.

I am going to show my code for whoever can and wants to guide me. I would appreciate very much

```
#BACK OFFICE ROUTES-PACIENTES
resources :patients do
  resources :evolutions
end

CONTROLLERS:
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @patient = current_user.patients.new patient_params
    if @patient.save
      return redirect_to patients_url, notice: 'El paciente fue agregado con exito'
    end
    render :new
  end

class EvolutionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user! 

  def index
    @evolutions = @patient.Evolution.all
  end
  def new
    @evolution = Evolution.new
  end

  def edit
  end
  
  def create
    @evolution = current_user.evolutions.new evolution_params
    if @evolution.save
      return redirect_to patients_url, notice: 'La evolucion fue agregada con exito'
    end
    render :new
  end 

  def show
    @evolution = Evolution.find params[:id]
  end

  private 

  def evolution_params
    params.require(:evolution).permit(:motivo, :evolution, :patient_id)
  end
end
```

As I was saying, the patients have no problems, but the evolutions I cannot save in the database.

Comment: could you show patient/evolution models/views and the error (you could use `@evolution.save!` to know what error)

Answer (score 0):

I expect your `ApplicationController` already has a `before_action :authenticate_user!`, otherwise `current_user` wouldn't be working in your `PatientsController`. So, you can remove that.

In your `Evolutions#index` action you refer to the instance variable `@patient` despite this not having been set anywhere. Based on your routes this is a nested resource under `Patient`, and so your `index` action should look something like this:

```
def index
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]
  @evolutions = @patient.evolutions # You could skip this and just use @patient.evolutions in your view if you like
end
```

Likewise, your `new` action should be modified to generate a new evolution for a specific patient:

```
def new
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]
  @evolution = @patient.evolutions.build
end
```

This will create a new, unsaved instance of `Evolution` which already belongs to the appropriate user.

Finally, we need to update the `create` action to handle the nested resource also:

```
def create
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]
  @evolution = @patient.evolutions.build(evolution_params)

  if @evolution.save
    redirect_to patients_url, notice: 'La evolucion fue agregada con exito'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

As you can see, we now have repeated code in our actions for finding the `Patient` from the params ... we can DRY this up by moving it to a before action.

Pulling this all together:

```
class EvolutionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_patient

  def index
    @evolutions = @patient.evolutions # You could skip this and just use @patient.evolutions in your view if you like
  end

  def show
    @evolution = @patient.evolutions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @evolution = @patient.evolutions.build
  end

  def create
    @evolution = @patient.evolutions.build(evolution_params)

    if @evolution.save
      redirect_to patients_url, notice: 'La evolucion fue agregada con exito'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  private
    def load_patient
      @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]
    end

    def evolution_params
      params.require(:evolution).permit(:motivo, :evolution, :patient_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect for me, but I have noticed that it does not save me on the first try, it only saves me when I restart the browser

Comment: You'll need to post some logs or errors or something for me to understand what's going on there.